# Encontrar arquivos em drives locais usando Batch

Tags: windows, batch

Bom dia prezados,

meu conhecimento em script é bem limitado e por isso gostaria de contar com a ajuda da comunidade na seguinte questão.

Temos alguns arquivos excel de nomes específicos nos computadores dos usuários. (suponhamos: file1.xls, file2.xls e file3.xls) Quero rodar uma batch para buscar por estes arquivos específicos.

Gostaria então que um log txt com o nome do computador fosse criado numa pasta da rede apontando o resultado (as pastas que contém aqueles arquivos).

Algumas considerações:

A batch será executada localmente usando um deploy através de software automatos, sendo assim, o usuário executando a batch será o system;

-Eu não quero que o usuário saiba que esta busca está sendo executada;

-Caso os arquivos não existam na máquina do usuário, não há necessidade do log, bastando à batch ser interrompida.

Como eu disse, não tenho muito conhecimento avançado em script, o que eu descobri até agora é que posso usar o DIR para buscar o arquivo e imprimir em tela conforme abaixo:

```
dir setup.txt /s
```

Mas claro, além de ser super simples, o código não define caminhos e nem tampouco busca em outros drives locais além do C. Vale dizer ainda que usuários possuem pastas de rede mapeadas e eu não quero buscar dentro destas.

Minha pergunta é: como traduzir minha necessidade em código?

Agradeço de imediato a quem se prontificar a ajudar. Qualquer ideia será bem vinda e testada de acordo.

Obrigado e um ótimo dia a todos

*Update:

Encontrei esse código aqui que já é alguma coisa. Ele não imprime os resultados da busca no log txt com o caminho dos arquivos encontrados, mas já me fala se os arquivos existem ou não:

```
dir /s /a-d setup.txt >nul && (echo found it) || (echo not found)
```

Quem puder me ajudar aprimorando de imediato agradeço.

Comment: somente na Raiz da unidade, ou subpastas, de subpastas, etc, também?

Comment: @David Subpastas também. Se possível em todas as unidades que não sejam de rede ou drive de cv/dvd. Caso isso não seja possível, no drive c todo.

Answer (score 1):

Acabei eu mesmo encontrando uma ideia e desenvolvendo posteriormente a solução.

Compartilho aqui para ajudar quem tiver a mesma necessidade que eu futuramente.

```
@echo off

rem Muda o local de execução do script para a pasta desejada. 
pushd C:\

rem Faz a busca em todos os arquivos da pasta e da subpasta desejados. Para buscar mais de um arquivo adicione a opção /s novamente seguida do nome do arquivo.
rem Caso não saiba a extensão ou o nome todo do arquivo use * antes ou depois do nome, em parte ou em todo o nome da extensão também.   
rem No exemplo abaixo, caso encontre os arquivos especificados, ele pula para a linha printresult. Caso não encontre vá para o notfound.
dir /s /a-d "setup.txt" /s "setup2.txt" >nul && (goto printresult) || (goto notfound)

:printresult
rem Ao encontrar os arquivos o script produz um log em txt na pasta apontada, usando o nome da máquina como nome do arquivo em frente à palavra FOUND.
dir /s /a-d setup.txt /s setup2.txt >>"\\servidor\pastadelogs\FOUND_%computername%.txt

rem A opção abaixo retorna o prompt para o local inicial
popd
exit


:notfound
rem Caso não encontre os arquivos o script gera um log usando o nome da máquina como nome do arquivo em frente à palavra NOTFOUND. 
echo "Este PC não possui os arquivos" >>"\\servidor\pastadelogs\NOTFOUND_%computername%.txt
popd
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

---

### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu **entendi** o que **busca**:

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

set /a "_cnt=0" & set "_arqui="%temp%\_setup_file_.log"" & set "_ocorr=ocorrencias" 
echo/ & set "_busca=setup.txt" & del /q /f !_arqui! 2>nul >nul & type nul >!_arqui!

echo/Buscando Arquivos... & type nul >!_arqui! & title <nul & title Q116162
2>nul >nul (
for /f "tokens=*delims= " %%i in ('where /r "." !_busca!')do echo/%%~i>>!_arqui!
for %%a in (!_arqui!) do for /f "tokens=3delims=:" %%b in ('find /v /c "" "%%a"')do set /a _cnt=%%b)
(type !_arqui!|findstr . >nul||goto :^[ ) & if !_cnt! leq 1 set "_ocorr=!_ocorr:~0,-1!" 

:^)
choice /m "Abrir o arquivo log? [ Sim(s) | Nao(n) ] : " & if !errorlevel! == 1 ( 
call start "" /b Notepad.exe !_arqui! & copy /y !_arqui! "%~dp0\" /y 2>nul >nul 
echo/ & echo/RESULTADOS: Busca retornou !_cnt! !_ocorr! para sua busca [!_busca!] & exit /b) else (
:^[
if !_cnt! equ 0 echo. & echo/ERROR: Busca retorna sem !_ocorr:~,-1! para [!_busca!] & exit /b)
```